# Translate Knockout Variables

Tags: magento2.3, shipping, localisation, i18n

I've been trying to get the shipping titles to translate with no success so far. It seems most questions deal with knockout text but I'm trying to do it on a variable that doesn't seem to be working. Here's what I want to translate, which is located in app/design/frontend/Me/Mylook/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/shipping-rates.html:

```
<!-- ko i18n: $data.method_title --><!-- /ko -->
```

And here's what I've been using in the CSV files locally

```
"Free Shipping", "Test Shipping"
```

I've tried this CSV file in the following places with no luck:

```
app/code/i18n/en_US.csv
app/code/i18n/magento/checkout/en_US.csv
app/code/MyCompany/Translate/i18n/en_US.csv
app/code/design/frontend/Me/Mylook/i18n/en_US.csv
app/code/design/frontend/Me/Mylook/Magento_Checkout/i18n/en_US.csv
```

I've cleared cache, redeployed static content and deployed static content with just that language (en_US) and cleared browser cache multiple times.

I have tried to alter the js-translate.json file directly in pub/static and if I add the text it'll work, but that only works as long as I don't clear cache.

Any ideas before I do something horrible and try to update the text with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

For translation is:

```
<!-- ko i18n: -->
```

not

```
<!-- ko text:  -->
```

in this file is ko text.

You can change in backend:

Stores => Configurations => Sales => Shipping Methods=> Free Shipping=> Title

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me still. Cleared cache a few times. I feel like this should be the way to go (other translations in the file work) but it's not working for the knockout variable.

Comment: Please check update